# Is there an in built processor in Apache NiFi which can create a Password enabled SSH connection?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an HDInsight Cluster setup on Azure Cloud. Also have installed Apache NiFi on a separate VM. Please Note I have SCP & SSH access enabled from VM to my cluster. I am trying to setup some processors as per my requirement, first one in the list is an "ExecuteProcess" processor. What I am trying to achieve through that is to establish an SSH connection with my HDInsight Cluster and once that's successful pass that result (connection established = 'Y') through a FlowFile to my second processor which is a "GetFile" processor that will basically read a JSON file from a particular path in that HDInsight cluster.

I have added "ExecuteProcess" processor and in the Configure option -> Properties section, have set the below:

Command : ssh sshdepuser@demodepdata-ssh.azurehdinsight.net
command arguments: sshdepuser@demodepdata-ssh.azurehdinsight.net
Batch Duration : No Value Set
Redirect Error System : True
Working Directory : No Value Set
Argument Delimiter : No Value Set

Command : ssh sshdepuser@demodepdata-ssh.azurehdinsight.net
command arguments: sshdepuser@demodepdata-ssh.azurehdinsight.net
Batch Duration : No Value Set
Redirect Error System : True
Working Directory : No Value Set
Argument Delimiter : No Value Set

Please Note sshdepuser@demodepdata-ssh.azurehdinsight.net is the server hostname for my HDInsight Cluster to which I am trying to establish connectivity from my VM (Server DNS Name : dep-hadoop.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com)

I am trying to setup some processors as per my requirement, first one in the list is an "ExecuteProcess" processor. What I am trying to achieve through that is to establish an SSH connection with my HDInsight Cluster and once that's successful pass that result (connection established = 'Y') through a FlowFile to my second processor which is a "GetFile" processor that will basically read a JSON file from a particular path in that HDInsight cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that this doesn't work this way, you are not going to be able to pass an ssh  connection as a flow file, nut you can try a workaround: in the execute processor, instead of make only an ssh connection, copy also the file to a local folder, then you can use the GetFile processor.

Comment: Hi Oscar, Thanks for responding mate. Can you please assist me in how I can copy the file to a local folder along with establishing the ssh connection in GetFile processor ?

Comment: If you can use directly scp use it instead of the ssh command with the ExecuteProcess processor.